# filter mule esb json payload based on request param

Tags: json, filter, mule, dataweave

I want to filter my json data based on my request. so if my request is like `/user` it gives me the full json data as result and if i give `/user?bikes` it filters me the result with json result with bike data and if i use `/user?cars` it filters me json data with car as result. Below is my json payload .

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": {
        "car1": "Ford",
        "car2": "BMW",
        "car3": "Fiat"
    },
    "bikes": {
        "bike1": "ducati",
        "bike2": "BMW",
        "bike3": "honda"
    }
}
```

so `/user` will give full data

`/user?bikes` will be -

```
{
     "bikes": {
        "bike1": "ducati",
        "bike2": "BMW",
        "bike3": "honda"
    }
}
```

`/user?cars` will be -

```
{
 "cars": {
        "car1": "Ford",
        "car2": "BMW",
        "car3": "Fiat"
    }
}
```

Please let me know how this can be used using mulesoft

Comment: It looks like the query params aren't formatted correctly it should be something like `?key=value&key=value` instead of `?key`. Also, which version of Mule are you running?

Comment: hi i am using mule 3.9.. and yes query param will be like ?key=value&key=value

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that.